# Switch git branch not updating files

Tags: git, git-branch

I have created a new branch and added some files.

Locally I use tortoise GIT and when I switch to the new branch, the files are updated.

On my production server using CLI, when I switch to the new branch with `git checkout mynewbranch`, the files are not updated.

When I switch with `git checkout origin/mynewbranch`, the files are updated but i get the following message:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits     
you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing 
another checkout.
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears as if you already have a local branch with the name `mynewbranch` but this branch does not have the recent changes that you're looking for.  Those changes do exist in the origin, however.  Because of this, when you `git checkout origin/mynewbranch` you are able to see the changes.  If you want to pull these changes into your local `mynewbranch` branch, issue the following commands:

```
git checkout mynewbranch
git pull . origin/mynewbranch
```